# WPF - Lost ability to input date via keyboard?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a WPF user control that makes use of a ComboBox to contain a DatePicker.  Unfortunately, when I put the DatePicker into the ComboBox, I seem to lose the ability to enter the date through the keyboard; only the Calendar and mouse work.

Any ideas?

Also, here's my XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboCombo" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=Foreground}" DropDownOpened="cboCombo_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="cboCombo_DropDownClosed">
            <ComboBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeTextConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="SelectedDateAndTime" Mode="OneWay" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="ShowTime" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ComboBox.Text>
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
                <ComboBoxItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=SelectedDateAndTime}" SelectedDateChanged="BCDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" />
                            <controls:TimePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="TimePicker_MouseUp" Loaded="TimePicker_Loaded" Time="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=SelectedDateAndTime,Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=ShowTime, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />

                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Today" Click="Button_Click" />
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Clear" Click="Button_Click_1" />

                            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="View Date Calculator" Click="Button_Click_2" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=ShowDateCalculator,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=SelectedDateAndTime,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource HolidayDateConverter}}" Foreground="Red" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ComboBoxItem.Template>
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with the ComboBox control handling the KeyBoard events, but why do you want a DatePicker in a ComboBox in the first place?

Comment: If you only want to support certain dates, I believe the DatePicker can already support that - you don't need to build it into a combo box.  If you're trying to support different types of fields there, then this combination is *not* the best way to do it, not just from a programming perspective, but also from a user experience perspective.  I'd suggest investigating other ideas, like a set of radio buttons paired with a control for each field type, and enabling only the control that corresponds with the selected radio button.

Comment: The reason it's in a combobox is that I wanted the "popup" functionality of the calendar, but I also needed additional options such as selection of a time as well as a date, buttons to select Today or Clear the date, and also a label is display whether or not the selected date is a holiday.

I'm definitely open to other suggestions that meet these requirements.

Comment: If you want all that functionality, then use separate controls for those *separate* functionality.  A DatePicker for the date, some kind of Time Picker (roll your own or look online) for the time, a Button to set the DatePicker to today's date, a CheckBox (or TextBlock) for your IsHoliday...  To try to roll it into one list is a little, well, kooky.

Comment: Not really.  Why should I create 200 controls in my project, followed by 200 more methods to set and reset values when twenty usercontrols will suffice?  Isn't that the whole point of having user controls?  Encapsulate the desired bahvior into one package.

Answer (score 0):

I would try mode=twoway and make sure there is a get set on the property and take off the event. I understand you want the event but if the event is is breaking it then at least you know the event is breaking it. And you can trace and see if set if fired.  I am with the other comments - why do you want to do this?